# Implementing acknowledge packet

Tags: c, sockets, tcp, packet

I'm trying to implement a simple instant messenger server and came up with the following problem:

How can I implement a protocol with a acknowledge packet?

I think it could be implemented like this:

```
>> client sends packet with ACKID and waits for ACKID to arrive
<< server receives packet and sends the same ACKID back
now the client knows the packet was fully delivered.
```

But in this concept, the client would block until the ACKID was sent back, and if another packet interrupts this process then the client would block forever (or until timeout occurs).

Comment: The answer is simple; you don't block.  There is no reason to block.  You can wait for the ACK and timeout if it took too long.

Comment: @EdS. Can you give an example, please?

Comment: Why would another packet interrupt this process? Only the peer can send to you.

Comment: Waiting for a packet to arrive doesn't require blocking inside a blocking-recv() call.  You could instead handle the waiting by calling select(), poll(), or other some mechanism that will notify you when the packet has arrived but doesn't prevent you from doing other things in the meantime.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are sending data like this at the moment:

```
Send("mydata");
```

Now, do this:

```
Send("mydata");
auto ack = Receive();
assert(ack == "data acknowledged");
```

(In pseudo-code).

Use a timeout for both operations. Only when the Receive completes without error you know that the data was received.

The same principle can be translated to async IO APIs. This is immaterial to the question.

(Stop talking about "packets" in the context of TCP. TCP does not know what that is.)